# How to edit XML values using SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an `XML` column `UserDetails` in a SQL Server database which has value like this:

```
<fleet>
    <Setting name="city"/>
    <UserSettings name="details">
        <UserSettings name="A1">
            <setting type="1" name="email"/>
            <setting value="user"/>
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A2">
            <setting type="2" name="phone"/>
            <setting value="technician"/>
        </UserSettings>
    </UserSettings>     
</fleet>
```

I would to read from the db and add a new setting in

```
<UserSettings name="A2"> .
```

Can someone point me to what I should be doing?

Comment: [Here is a good place to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `sql:variable()` to introduce a value you've created externally. And you can use `Xml.exist()` to find XMLs which haven't got this new entry before:

```
DECLARE @myTbl TABLE(Descr VARCHAR(100),TheXml XML);            
INSERT INTO @myTbl VALUES
(   
'Setting "A3" doesn''t exist','<fleet>
    <Setting name="city" />
    <UserSettings name="details">
        <UserSettings name="A1">
            <setting type="1" name="email" />
            <setting value="user" />
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A2">
            <setting type="2" name="phone" />
            <setting value="technician" />
        </UserSettings>
    </UserSettings>
</fleet>'
)
,(   
'Setting "A3" exists already','<fleet>
    <Setting name="city" />
    <UserSettings name="details">
        <UserSettings name="A1">
            <setting type="1" name="email" />
            <setting value="user" />
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A2">
            <setting type="2" name="phone" />
            <setting value="technician" />
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A3">
            <setting type="3" name="A3 setting" />
            <setting value="this exists already" />
        </UserSettings>
    </UserSettings>
</fleet>'
);  

DECLARE @NewSetting XML=
      N'<UserSettings name="A3">
            <setting type="3" name="new A3" />
            <setting value="new data" />
        </UserSettings>';


UPDATE @myTbl
SET TheXml.modify('             
insert sql:variable("@NewSetting")
as last into (/fleet/UserSettings)[1]')           
WHERE TheXml.exist(N'/fleet/UserSettings[@name="details"]/UserSettings[@name="A3"]')=0;  

SELECT * FROM @myTbl
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER provides methods to [modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) XML data, and a language to do it ([XML DML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-modification-language-xml-dml)).
You need to use the modify method with an insert xml dml statement.

Here is the complete example:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml;            
SET @myDoc =   
'<fleet>
    <Setting name="city" />
    <UserSettings name="details">
        <UserSettings name="A1">
            <setting type="1" name="email" />
            <setting value="user" />
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A2">
            <setting type="2" name="phone" />
            <setting value="technician" />
        </UserSettings>
    </UserSettings>
</fleet>';
```

The statement:

```
SET @myDoc.modify('             
insert <setting value="NEW SETTINGS" />
as first into (/fleet/UserSettings/UserSettings[@name="A2"])[1] ') ;           
SELECT @myDoc;
```

Result:

```
<fleet>
    <Setting name="city" />
    <UserSettings name="details">
        <UserSettings name="A1">
            <setting type="1" name="email" />
            <setting value="user" />
        </UserSettings>
        <UserSettings name="A2">
            <setting value="NEW SETTINGS" />
            <setting type="2" name="phone" />
            <setting value="technician" />
        </UserSettings>
    </UserSettings>
</fleet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ..Is it not possible to get the column value as xml and insert the new setting if its not found? ...

Comment: I guess there is, but I don't know how. I've answered your question mainly because it was an opportunity for me to learn more about SQL Server's XML support. I suggest using the links I gave you both in the comment and in the answer and learn, just like I did.